# How to regenerate md file from public dir in hexo？

Tags: hexo

I use hexo to generate github blog. However, I deleted my source dir by an accident and now I only have public file, Is there any method to regenerate from html file into .md file ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this, you can write code to parse html to markdown depends on your theme layout. Or you could try [HTML to Markdown](https://domchristie.github.io/to-markdown/).

If your posts is not too many, I would suggest copy your content in browser and write markdown files again. This time, please remember to put your source in version control such as [Github](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/), so you could recover easily.